# is it Possible to bevel the edges of this extruded Ngon?

Tags: modeling, bevel

or make them look not as sharp? i have tried using the bevel shader node but it is still very sharp. and bevel modifier results are crazy.
[image]

Comment: The vertices are too densely placed, so when you try to bevel you'll get self-intersections. My best suggestion is to check out some retopology tutorials on Youtube. There are plenty, most of which are targeted at character retopo, but the techniques can be applied to other stuff as well. A quick fix might be using the _Remesh_ modifier followed by the _Smooth_ modifier, but that'll give you a ridiculous vertex count.

Comment: to add to the previous comment, if you don't care about accuracy, you can try a X > Limited Dissolve to remove some vertices (play with the Angle value in the Operator box) in order to avoid overlapping faces when you'll bevel